# Alert in PHP not working inside if

Tags: javascript, php

I want to put an alert inside an if (in a php document) with other actions. The other actions works fine but not the alert. Can anybody help me?. This is where the alert is:

```
if(empty($response)){ 
    //SOME ACTIONS
    echo '<script type='text/javascript'> alert("Message´s 1st line\nMessage´s 2nd line");</script>';
    //SOME ACTIONS
    header('Location: SOMEWEBSITE');                                
}else{ 
   //ANOTHER ACTION
}
```

All actions works fine except for the alert. I tried on different browsers but the alert doesnt appear.

Sorry for my english

Thank you all.

Comment: The SO syntax highlighting should give you a clue as to your issue.

Comment: Check your inverted commas `type='text/javascript'` should be doubles `type="text/javascript"`and you might want `language="javascript"` If the apostrophes were not backticks you would need to escape those `Message\'s` like that. Usually you want `exit;` after the location redirect to stop the rest of the page loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This    `echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Message´s 1st line\nMessage´s 2nd line");</script>'`

Comment: Still nothing, this is really strange, I also tried outside the "if" and doesnt work either. Thanks anyway Mohaimin

Comment: Than try this by defining a function ,,,,                                                   <?php
function phpAlert($msg) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . $msg . '")</script>';
}
?>                                                                                                           and then                                                                                                <?php phpAlert(   "Hello world!\\n\\nPHP has got an Alert Box"   );  ?>

Comment: Finally, thank you very much Mohaimin now works fine. (Y)

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if you use below mentioned code.

```
if(empty($response)){ 
//SOME ACTIONS
?>
 <script type="text/javascript"> alert("Message´s 1st line\nMessage´s 2nd line");</script>
<?php
//SOME ACTIONS
header('Location: SOMEWEBSITE');                                
}else{ 
//ANOTHER ACTION
}
```

Comment: Thank you Waleed, but still nothing.

Answer (score 2):

First thing is to fix quotes.

Second thing is remove `header()` call

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Remember that `header()` must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

And don't use `location` header for 200 response

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location

Answer (score 2):

Yes fix your quote.

The bellow code should work which you tried if you don't use redirection.

```
echo '<script language="javascript">alert("message");</script>';
```

You can't expect alert where you redirecting to another page from php. If you use javascript redirection, then it can be work. Replace redirection line with something like

```
echo '<script language="javascript">window.location = "http://SOMEWEBSITE.COM";</script>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Message´s 1st line\nMessage´s 2nd line');</script>";
```

The code that you wrote the echo was terminating after

```
type='
```

Comment: Sorry I dont understand, I tried also with: echo '<script language="javascript">alert("message");</script>';  from a previous working job but didnt work either.